# How to get a live preview of my website

Tags: javascript, browser, firebug, live, preview

cssdesk, jsbin and such do a wonderful job of showing a live preview side by side with your code.  I wonder if there is a way to just get the live preview.

Ideally, I would open my text editor or ide on one monitor, and a browser on another monitor, and while I adjust the code in my ide, and save my document, the browser would sense the change, and update the page.

Would this need to built as a browser extension, maybe it can be built in javascript and offered for free to any developer who would like to use it.

I feel like this would be a great feature for firebug or something.

Comment: I just set up my window manager so that refreshing and jumping back to the text editor is easy - in my case, Ctrl-E (go to right monitor), Ctrl-R (reload), Ctrl-W (go to left monitor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is LiveJS, which does exactly this:

http://livejs.com/